# Uncovering a table, cell by cell, using beamer

Tags: beamer

I have the following MWE (taken from the Beamer User Guide) which allows me to uncover a table row by row.

I would like to be able to uncover the contents of a table, cell by cell.

```
%Preamble
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
 \begin{frame}
  \begin{tabular}{l!{\vrule}cccc}
    Class & A & B & C & D \\\hline
    X & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \pause\\
    Y & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \pause\\
    Z & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8
  \end{tabular}
 \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
 \begin{frame}
  \begin{tabular}{l|cccc}
    Class & A & B & C & D \\\hline
    \visible<+->{X} & \visible<+->{1} & \visible<+->{2} & \visible<+->{3} & \visible<+->{4} \pause\\
    \visible<+->{Y} & \visible<+->{3} & \visible<+->{4} & \visible<+->{5} & \visible<+->{6} \pause\\
    \visible<+->{Z} & \visible<+->{5} & \visible<+->{6} & \visible<+->{7} & \visible<+->{8}
  \end{tabular}
 \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: .@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Can I achieve the same output without writing `\visible<+->` in all these cells, explicitly?

Answer (score 2):

The following MWE will uncover the first row of the table cell by cell.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
 \begin{frame}
  \begin{tabular}{l!{\vrule}cccc}
    Class & A & B & C & D \\\hline
    X & 1 \pause & 2  \pause & 3 \pause & 4 \pause\\
    Y & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \pause\\
    Z & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8
  \end{tabular}
 \end{frame}
\end{document}
```